# left null space of a matrix $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have a matrix $V$ and a row vector $\mathbf{a}=(a_1 \cdots a_d)$.

Define $a^{\|}$ to be such that $aV = (a^{\perp}+a^{\|})V = \mathbf{0} + a^{\|}V$, where $a^{\|}$ and $a^{\perp}$ are orthogonal to each other.

Is there a relationship between the magnitude of elements of $a^{\|}$ and the magnitude of row vectors of $V$?

More specifically, if $a^{\|}=(a^*_1 \cdots a^*_d)$, does the magnitude of $a^*_i$ have positive correlation with the $L_2$ norm of $i$-th row vector of $V$? (i.e. if the magnitude of $a^*_i$ is relatively large compared to other elements in $a^{\|}$, then would the $L_2$ norm of the $i$ th row vector of $V$ be also relatively larger than the $L_2$ norm of other row vectors in $V$?)

I sense that this can be impossible to answer. But I am just curious about whether such a relationship holds. If this is something that is impossible to know, then please indicate that as an answer.

Thank you,

Comment: Note that the decomposition of $a$ into $a = a^\perp + a^{||}$ is not unique unless we impose an additional condition, e.g. that $a^\perp$ and $a^{\|}$ are orthogonal to each other

Comment: Good point, I will revise my post accordingly. Indeed, $a^{\|}$ and $a^{\perp}$ are perpendicular to each other

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am sorry to bother you with my question, but could you please answer my question if you can? I am sorry for taking your time.

Comment: I haven't had time today, but I might get a chance to take a look tomorrow

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you very much, I appreciate your offer for help.